# Travis Multi-Architecture Buiilds

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I've got a project that I'm attempting to build for arm and x86_64.

The x86_64 build passes but the arm build fails with:

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for kutsudock/rpi-alpine-go:latest
standard_init_linux.go:175: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

Here's my yaml:

```
env:
  global:
    - VERSION=1.${TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER}
  matrix:
    - ARCH=x86_64
      GOIMG=golang:1.6
      DOCKER_BUILD=mastermindg/docker-flow-proxy:${VERSION}
      DOCKERFILE=Dockerfile.amd64
    - ARCH=rpi
      GOIMG=kutsudock/rpi-alpine-go
      DOCKER_BUILD=mastermindg/docker-flow-proxy:rpi-${VERSION}
      DOCKERFILE=Dockerfile.rpi

sudo: required

services:
  - docker

script:
  - docker run --rm -v $PWD:/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp -v go:/go ${GOIMG} bash -c "cd /usr/src/myapp && go get -d -v -t && go test --cover -v ./... --run UnitTest && go build -v -o docker-flow-proxy"

after_success:
  - docker build -t ${DOCKER_BUILD} -f ${DOCKERFILE} .
  - '[ "${TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST}" = "false" ] && docker login -e $DOCKER_EMAIL -u $DOCKER_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD || false'
  - '[ "${TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST}" = "false" ] && docker push ${DOCKER_BUILD} || false'

branches:
  only:
    - master
```

**How can I get the arm Docker images to build on Travis?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking over Travis I found this issue:

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/3376

Thanks to @moul Debian has a multi-arch bootstrap. Simply register the qemu before your Docker runs and it works!

In your case:

```
docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static:register
docker run --rm -v $PWD:/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp -v go:/go ${GOIMG} bash -c "cd /usr/src/myapp && go get -d -v -t && go test --cover -v ./... --run UnitTest && go build -v -o docker-flow-proxy"
```

Answer (score 2):

Last week TravisCI announced multi-architecture support which includes Arm support now and is free for all open source projects. Please see the this blog post: https://blog.travis-ci.com/2019-10-07-multi-cpu-architecture-support

Answer (score 0):

The way to use ARM 64-bit (aarch64) and ARM 32-bit (armv7l) is like this:

```
docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static:register --reset

docker run --rm -t multiarch/ubuntu-debootstrap:arm64-bionic uname -a
Linux 28c784e9c7bc 4.4.0-101-generic #124~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 10 19:05:36 UTC 2017 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

docker run --rm -t multiarch/ubuntu-debootstrap:armhf-bionic uname -a
Linux 4de7b4e919b0 4.4.0-101-generic #124~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 10 19:05:36 UTC 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

See also https://github.com/junaruga/ci-multi-arch-test

Answer (score 0):

```
before_script:
    - wget https://github.com/riotkit-org/ci-utils/archive/v2.0.0.zip -O /tmp/ci-utils.zip  # change master to a release tag only here (version)
    - curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/riotkit-org/ci-utils/master/ci-integration/travis.sh" -s | bash

    # activate ARM builds on travis
    - /opt/riotkit/utils/bin/setup-travis-arm-builds
```

Check also: https://github.com/riotkit-org/ci-utils